# What the word to describe this phenomenon?

Tags: computer-science

I wrote a program, it returned an error. But if I reopen it, run it again, it return the right answer perfectly.I remember **Wiki** have this item,but I can't remember.

Comment: It's not a real world, but I've heard "heisenbug" used. From "Heisenberg uncertainty principle" + "bug".

Comment: @Patrick87 Yes,you got it. Heisenbug - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia

Comment: Not a real word, not *world*. Please feel free answer your own question if you like... then accept it so others can find what you wanted.

Comment: @Patrick87 But it exist in world in mathematica,so I don't understand your meaning.

Comment: I just mean to say that "heisenbug" is not a real "English word" as your question asks for, but more of a slang term used by programmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Intermittent Error** - An error that occurs sporadically, not consistently. It is the most difficult type of problem to diagnose and repair.

Comment: I would say that an incomplete bug report by an end user is even more difficult to diagnose and repair :-)

Answer (score 0):

***[UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176333/2411320)***.

---

It's a phrase, not a word. You are just (un)lucky it executed properly the second time.